Error with llamaindex NL2SQL, agent gets query 100% right but engine returns no data:
Working on an OpenAI (gpt-3.5-turbo-0613) RAG chat agent and the agent is taking the prompt, accurately translating to the correct SQL query and running it, but I get this response:
=== Calling Function === Calling function: AG-Database-Query with args: {"input":"SELECT CLIENT FROM CLIENT_DELIVERY"} Got output: Error: None.H
Yet, if I copy/paste that query into SSMS I get the proper result. The code uses SQLAlchemy to connect to the database, so I hard-coded the same query against the SQLAlchemy connection and I get a valid result. Somewhere in the libraries of the llama_index agent, to the llama_index query_engine it is losing the ability to connect to get a query response. I'm happy to provide additional code, just wondering if anyone has seen this?
The primary code chunks are:
sql_query_engine = NLSQLTableQueryEngine(
        sql_database = sql_database,
        tables=table_name,
)

sql_tool = QueryEngineTool.from_defaults(
        query_engine=sql_query_engine,
        name="AG-Database-Query",
        description=DESCRIPTION,
)
agent = OpenAIAgent.from_tools(
        tools=[sql_tool],
        context=context,
        verbose=True
)


Did you ever resolve this? Having the same issue with Snowflake. The query returned by the LLM works perfectly in the Snowflake console but Agent throws an error.
